# proof given for spheres to be done for manifolds

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds, reflection, orientation

All

I am looking at the following theorem in the book of Bredon and my question is how does it work for manifolds instead of spheres? The proof is understood, but I am wondering if it is enough to just said that it also works for manifolds? Since taking at each point of given manifold a sphere, we establish orientations locally which are all consistent, so global orientation for manifold is chosen. So we have this theorem for such each sphere, which means it should hold for the whole manifold, as that orientations coincide. Could you please advise if my understanding is correct or give a hint how should I proceed for manifolds?

[image]

Comment: There are manifolds which are not orientable, so it is difficult to make sense of what you want to do...

Comment: First of all the antipode map need not be well defined for general manifold $M\subseteq\mathbb{R}^m$. And even if it is then the proof is done by induction on $n$. So how would you do that for general manifolds? As induction on $\text{dim}(M)$? Then it fails in zero dimension, e.g. $M=\{0\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ then the antipode map is the identity map, hence of degree $1$.